# Barplots in R: Strange Empty 1st Column

Tags: r, formatting, bar-chart

The following code creates a Barplot in R. However, the 1st column is empty. I don't understand why... There is no NA values in my data set. How can I remove the space between the "Bayview Column" and the Y-Axis?

```
# 2. Bar Plot for Police District
barplot(xtabs(~sample$PoliceDistrict), 
        main="Police District Distribution of Incidents", 
        xlab="Number of Incidents in Police District",
        ylab="Frequency",
        col=rainbow(nlevels(as.factor(sample$PoliceDistrict))),
        las=2,
        # cex.lab=0.50 This is for the x-axis Label,
        cex.names = 0.45
        )
```

Here is the resulting Barplot with the 1st empty column:

[image]

Comment: Is the following a typo, xtabs(~sample$PoliceDistrict) which should read, xtabs~sample$PoliceDistrict) ?

Comment: What is the result of `levels(sample$PoliceDistrict)` ? I'm assuming you have a level which is blank - `""` - e.g. - `barplot(table(factor(c("One","One","Two","Two","Two"), levels=c("","One","Two") )))`

Comment: Yes you are right I have an empty level!. `[1] ""           "BAYVIEW"    "CENTRAL"    "INGLESIDE"  "MISSION"    "NORTHERN"   "PARK"       "RICHMOND"   "SOUTHERN"   "TARAVAL"    "TENDERLOIN"` I guess I need to remove the empty level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a blank factor level floating about, e.g.:

```
x <- factor(c("One","One","Two","Two","Two"), levels=c("","One","Two") )

levels(x)
#[1] ""    "One" "Two"

barplot(table(x))
## EXTRA BAR PLOTTED

x <- droplevels(x)
# ?droplevels
# The function ‘droplevels’ is used to drop unused levels from a
# factor or, more commonly, from factors in a data frame.

levels(x)
#[1] "One" "Two"

barplot(table(x))
## FIXED
```