# calculate the frequency in R

Tags: r, frequency, r-factor

Here is my data

```
> a
 [1] Male   Male   Female Male   Male   Male   Female Female Male   Male   Female Male   Male   Male  
[15] Female Female Female Male   Female Male   Female Male   Male   Female Male   Male   Female Male  
[29] Male   Male   Female Male   Male   Male   Female Female Male   Male   Male   Male   Male  
Levels:  Female Male

> b
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
Levels: 0 1

> table(a,b)
        b
a         0  1
          0  0
  Female 10  4
  Male   12 15
```

I don't know why the result of `table(a,b)` has a row of `(0  0)`, my expected result is as follows:

```
> table(a,b)
        b
a         0  1
  Female 10  4
  Male   12 15
```

Could you tell me why this happens and how to correct it, thank you!

```
> dput(a)
structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"Female", "Male"), class = "factor")

> dput(b)
structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Are the length of `a` and `b` the same?

Comment: you may have emptty  levels  of a ie `""`. Try `nlevels(a)`

Comment: @Psidom yes, the length of `a` and `b` is the same

Comment: Based on the extra space in `Levels:__Female Male`, I think @user20650 is right. If there were only two levels, it would be `Levels:_Female Male` (only one space, underscores are spaces).

Comment: As commented above, you may have an empty string in your vector `a`. Check that out.

Comment: @Psidom; it may not be an empty string, but an extra level

Comment: Essentially the same issue as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981564/barplots-in-r-strange-empty-1st-column/32981755

Comment: @user20650 Yeah, you got it. It does have an extra level there.

Comment: As you can see, you have three levels (`.Label`) in your `dput`. Fix your data entry problem and you'll fix the table. (Or just reassign the levels using, oddly enough, `levels(a) <- c("Female", "Male")`.)

Comment: Or use the droplevels command: `a<-droplevels(a)`

Comment: Thank all of you! @user20650 @Gregor @r2evans @Psidom  The original data is in a ".csv" form, then I used `read.csv("mydata.csv", header=T)` to read the data. And the list `a` is just one column of the input data frame, I used `dataframe$a` to extract that column, and there are no blanks in that column, a little weird. How came the `" "` level?

Comment: This will work with the example data: `table(as.character(a), b, useNA="no")`. Factors are always a little weird. I always try to use as=TRUE in my `read.` family of functions which converts variables to character rather than factor.

Comment: @Imo Yes, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above:

This is happening because there is an empty factor level in `a`:

```
> levels(a)
[1] ""       "Female" "Male"
```

You can keep produce a table that disregards empty factor levels (from @lmo's comment):

> ```
> table(as.character(a), b)
> ```

Alternatively, you can easily remove factor levels without observations (from @Dave2e's comment)

> ```
> a <- droplevels(a)
> table(a, b)
> ```